# Remove appended strings to StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

How do I remove the previously appended strings to my String Builder? If I have for example

```
result.append("$10.00");
result.append("+" + "$20.00");
result.append("+" + "$5.00");
```

How do I remove $5 and $20 respectively from a string which is now "`$10.00 + $20.00 + $5.00`"?

Comment: You need to change the approach you're using for a Calculator. Do not immediately append the values to the `StringBuilder` on user input. Rather do the final string creation when the operation is provided by the user. In any case, IMHO this approach looks a bit broken.

Comment: For what you're asking for, you should probably use an ArrayList (or equivalent) of Strings and concatenate them in the end when you're sure you're done. StringBuilder's API doesn't really contemplate your use case.

Answer (score 4):

Once you append it, it becomes "one" and you cant reverse

However you can use this in this case :

```
result.delete(result.lastIndexOf("+"), result.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no immediate way to do this.  I suggest you append each substring to a `List` or even to a `Stack`, and pop whatever you don't need out of your data structure.  When you are totally sure about what to present in your `StringBuilder`, start appending to it by running through your `Collection` and putting each substring into your final `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` method of StringBuilder to remove string, but you have to provide start and end position that you wants to remove.

For delete method description:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int, int)

Comment: StringBuilder is being used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't an easy way to do that.

Instead, you can store your results into an structure you can index, such as an ArrayList() and only construct your result string in the end, when you're sure about what is the data you want to append to your StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, where each dollar amount is seperated by a '+' character, I would go for the split method in the String class, after having made the string from the StringBuilder. If you could be a bit more specific about why you want to remove the strings again, that would help in choosing the right solution.

I guess what you are really looking for is a remove method on a StringBuilder object, but I am afraid such a thing does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question there it **doesn't required remove characters** from **output String**.

Since **Java 8** new **StringJoiner** class has been introduced.

```
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (String item : itemList) {
    stringJoiner.add(item)
}
```

For more information please read [StringJoiner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's one convenient way to remove if you are able to store the length of the StringBuilder before appending.

```java
result.append("$10.00");
int len = result.length();
result.append("+" + "$20.00");
// remove what is appended
result.setLength(len);
```